# Корректно объеденить условия в методе

Tags: java, android

На данный момент при выборе периода из options у меня отображается в текстовом формате всё корректно:

```
            periodFilterView.setText(currentFilter.getDatePeriod().periodDescription);
```

Но также во фрагменте есть поля для ввода дат, которые если прописываю следующее, то отображается также корректно (датами от и до):

```
            periodFilterView.setText(currentFilter.getDatePeriod().startDate.toString() + " / " + currentFilter.getDatePeriod().endDate.toString());
```

Но при попытке объеденить эти два условия в моём методе, отрабатывает лишь один и вместо текстового формата проставляются также даты.
Полный код метода:

```
private void updatePeriodFilterView() {
    if (currentFilter.isDefaultPeriod()) {
        periodFilterView.cleanText();
    } else if(!currentFilter.isDefaultPeriod()) {
        periodFilterView.setText(currentFilter.getDatePeriod().startDate.toString() + " / " + currentFilter.getDatePeriod().endDate.toString());
    } else {
        periodFilterView.setText(currentFilter.getDatePeriod().periodDescription);
    }
}
```

Comment: в каком случае должен сработать  последний else ?

Comment: У вас последний else недостижим, если isDefaultPeriod = true то выполнится первое условие, если false то второе.